# Autenticación LDAP Java usando nombre y sin contraseña

Tags: java, ldap

Tengo una aplicación que autentica los usuarios a través de Active Directory y Kerberos, una vez que pasa esta etapa, con el usuario logeado trato de verificar que pestañas o recursos puede ver de la aplicación a partir de una validación de LDAP.
Por ejemplo en mi Active Directory voy a tener grupos con usuarios habilitados para cada uno,

grupo1{
       user1,
       user3
}
grupo2{
       user3,
       user2
}

Mi problema está que a la hora de verificar si esta dentro de un grupo, me pide la contraseña,

mi código con contraseña es el siguiente y esta funcionando:

```
public boolean authenticate(String usuarioLogeado) throws Exception, NamingException {

    String ldapDn = "UserAdmin@TEST.COM";
    String ldapPassword = "UserAdmin_Pass";

    // Configuracion del entorno para crear el contexto inicial
    Hashtable<String, String> entorno = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    entorno.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    entorno.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://10.100.59.51:389");
    entorno.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
    entorno.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ldapDn);
    entorno.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ldapPassword);
    entorno.put(JAVA_NAMING_LDAP_VERSION, 3);

    Attributes atributos;
    DirContext contexto = null;

    boolean perteneceAlGrupo = false;

    try {

        // Se establece la conexion con LDAP
        contexto = new InitialDirContext(entorno);

        // Lista de atributos que se esperan obtener de la b�squeda
        String[] listaAtributos = { "sAMAccountName" };

        // Configura los controles de b�squeda
        SearchControls controles = new SearchControls();
        controles.setReturningAttributes(listaAtributos);
        controles.setSearchScope(2);

        // Filtro de b�squeda: Todos los miembros del grupo especificado
        String filtro = "(memberOf=" + ldapProperties.getRamaGroup() + ")";

        // Busca en el sub�rbol de objetos de LDAP que utilizan el filtro
        // dado
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> respuesta = contexto.search(ldapProperties.getBaseDn(), filtro, controles);

        // Recorre los objetos encontrados (Usuarios pertenecientes al
        // grupo)
        while (respuesta.hasMoreElements()) {

            // Un Usuario encontrado en el grupo
            SearchResult resultadoBusqueda = (SearchResult) respuesta.next();

            atributos = resultadoBusqueda.getAttributes();

            // Valor del atributo (Ej: rweimann)
            String usuarioGrupo = (String) atributos.get("sAMAccountName").get();

            // Verifica si el usuario del grupo es igual al usuario
            // ingresado por parametro
            if (usuarioGrupo.equalsIgnoreCase(usuarioLogeado)) {
                perteneceAlGrupo = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        contexto.close();

    } catch (AuthenticationException authEx) {
        //Usuario o password incorrectos
        return false;           

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }

    return perteneceAlGrupo;
}
```

Estoy interesado si existe la manera de realizar esta validación, pero sin la necesidad de introducir el pass del usuario. Estuve observando que se propone como solución tener un usuario administrador y logearse con este usuario para validar a los demás usuarios (version que estoy usando), pero esta no seria para mi caso una solución factible.